# Snap Firefox spams system logs with Apparmor / Mutter error

Tags: gnome, firefox, snap, apparmor

On my Ubuntu 23.10, during normal navigation Firefox adds lots of lines like this one to `/var/log/syslog`, so that the file gets bigger and bigger (it got to several gigabytes and filled up my disk):

```
dbus-daemon[361498]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.57" pid=545625 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=367416 peer_label="unconfined"
```

This seems similar to [Excessive Firefox related AppArmor log entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450727/excessive-firefox-related-apparmor-log-entries) , but the error is different.

Is this a bug with Firefox Apparmor's profile? Is there anything wrong in my configuration?